# JS Form Validation not working for simple html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple HTML form with just one filed. The form is as follows-

```
<table> 
    <form action="insert.php" method="post" name="discover" onSubmit="return discover()">
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="text"  name="name"></td></tr>                                                             
    <tr><td></td><td><br><br><p class="submit"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="commit" value="Register"></p><br><br><br></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

The validation js file is-

```
function discover() {
   var stu_name=document.forms["discover"]["name"].value;

   if (stu_name==null || stu_name=="" || stu_name.length<7) {
      alert("Please provide Your full name");
      return false;
   }  
}
```

I have included the validation js file properly. But the validation is not working.
The link for[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj5TR/)

Comment: all the answers above works my friend! are you testing in your PC or in JsFiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
var stu_name=document.forms["discover"]["stu_name"].value;
if (stu_name==null || stu_name=="" || stu_name.length<7)
  {
  alert("Please provide Your full name");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
<form action="" method="post" name="discover" id="discover" onsubmit="return check();">
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="stu_name" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="sub" />
</form>
```

Comment: +1, seems to work. Maybe you should explain what you exactly did?

Comment: you don't neet to add ID

Comment: function name and form name are same . that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your js file,

Test that:

```
function discover()
{
var stu_name=document.forms["discover"]["name"].value;


if (stu_name==null || stu_name=="" || stu_name.length<7)
{
      alert("Please provide Your full name");
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work

```
function discover()
{
var stu_name=document.getElementsByName("name");


if (stu_name==null || stu_name=="" || stu_name.length<7)
{
      alert("Please provide Your full name");
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: change the ** onSubmit="return discover()" ** to **onsubmit="discover()"**

Comment: changed. but same result.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing form name and function name and also the input needs an id which was missing. Also you forgot to close the function.
Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _discover()
{
var stu_name=document.forms["discover"]["stu_name"].value;


if (stu_name==null || stu_name=="" || stu_name.length<7)
  {
  alert("Please provide Your full name");
  return false;
  }
}


</script>

<table> 
    <form action="" method="post" name="discover" onSubmit="return _discover();">
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="text"  name="name" id="stu_name"> </td></tr>                                                             
    <tr><td></td><td><br><br><p class="submit"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="commit" value="Register"></p><br><br><br></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: did u use the function before the the form is loaded or in other words load the function in <head></head> since you are not using document.ready your Javascript should be loaded before the function is called.

Comment: I have used the function before the form is called. Please check jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

There is Nothing Wrong in your Code except the function name as same name as form

see this link here's the working code

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qagarunu/1/)

```
function disc() {
   var stu_name=document.forms["discover"]["name"].value;

   if (stu_name==null || stu_name=="" || stu_name.length<7) {
      alert("Please provide Your full name");
      return false;
   }  
}



<table> 
    <form action="insert.php" method="post" name="discover" onSubmit="return disc()">
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="text"  name="name"></td></tr>                                                             
    <tr><td></td><td><br><br><p class="submit"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="commit" value="Register"></p><br><br><br></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```